# InvalidCastException thrown when try to get SQL in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-3.1

I try to construct a dynamic expression work with filter in set such as `x => set.Contains(x.attr)` and get the generated SQL using below `.ToSQL()` method in EF Core 3.1.

But it throws an `InvalidCastException`:

> Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.VisitIn(InExpression inExpression)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression sqlBinaryExpression)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.VisitSelect(SelectExpression selectExpression)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.GetCommand(SelectExpression selectExpression)
>   at Microsoft.EcoManager.Domain.Core.QueryableExtensions.ToSql[TEntity](IQueryable`1 query)

Here is my code constructing filter set dynamic expression:

```
private static Expression<Func<TData, bool>> CreateSetFilterExpression<TData, TProperty>(string property, IEnumerable<TProperty> values)
{
    var type = typeof(TData);
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

    var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(property);
    Expression exp = Expression.Property(arg, propertyInfo);
    exp = Expression.Convert(exp, typeof(TProperty));

    var methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
                .GetMethods()
                .Single(x => x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains) && 
                             x.IsGenericMethodDefinition && 
                             x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && 
                             x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TProperty));
    var valuesExpr = Expression.Constant(values);

    exp = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, valuesExpr, exp);

    var resultLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TData, bool>>(exp, arg);
    return resultLambda;
}
```

It seems related to the `VisitIn` method of `QuerySqlGenerator` in EF Core:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2e8ef3516d2bed2f934eea6e2cb92f7a9ff40ab3/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/QuerySqlGenerator.cs#L624

For example, when I try to construct the filter set dynamic expression using `CreateSetFilterExpression<SomeEntity, int>(SomePropertyName, values)`, what the values' type is `List<int>`. It will throw `InvalidCastException` when executing to the line `sqlGenerator.GetCommand` in `ToSQL()`:

> Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.VisitIn(InExpression inExpression)
>   ...

I search about int cast to object, and check the boxing and unboxing concept in C#, but I still have no idea how to fix it.

Is that anyone has encountered the same problem?

Please help me if there is any clue about this problem?

Here is the code of `.ToSql()` method:

```cs
public static string ToSql<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query) where TEntity : class
{
    var enumerator = query.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(query.Expression).GetEnumerator();
    var relationalCommandCache = enumerator.Private("_relationalCommandCache");
    var selectExpression = relationalCommandCache.Private<SelectExpression>("_selectExpression");
    var factory = relationalCommandCache.Private<IQuerySqlGeneratorFactory>("_querySqlGeneratorFactory");

    var sqlGenerator = factory.Create();
    var command = sqlGenerator.GetCommand(selectExpression);

    string sql = command.CommandText;
    return sql;
}

private static object Private(this object obj, string privateField) => obj?.GetType().GetField(privateField, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(obj);

private static T Private<T>(this object obj, string privateField) => (T)obj?.GetType().GetField(privateField, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like property of TData class has got type Int32, but CreateSetFilterExpression() receives values as IEnumerable (and typeof(TProperty) == typeof(object)), EF can't translate that expression into SQL:

```
  exp = Expression.Convert(exp, typeof(TProperty));
```

Try to pass values as list of Int32 to the CreateSetFilterExpression().

Comment: passing values as List<int> thrown that exception as I mentioned in my post: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Object]'.

Comment: What is the type of TData property then?

Comment: That seems to be a bug in QuerySqlGeneratorFactory:
- If run query over database (without converting to SQL), it works correctly.
- If property has type string, SQL is being generated correctly

Comment: I think you are right. If I try not to get the generated SQL out, it seems work well.

Comment: TData property was just an entity (SomeEntity) which has a member named SomePropertyName in this example: property.CreateSetFilterExpression<SomeEntity, int>(SomePropertyName, values)

Comment: In my scenario, it just using EF core to generate the criteria in where clause, and get this SQL string out and add some query clause by raw string operation to get the final SQL to execute.